# ROWS must be positive in postgres

Tags: pgadmin-4

Hello experts I have created function in postgresql. It works fine  in pgadmin 3 and postgreslq 9.5 but when running the same scripts in pgadmin 4 and postgreql 10 it generates the following massages "ERROR:  ROWS must be positive SQL state: 22023".
`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION office.is_logged_in(
user_id_ integer)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 0
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM office.users 
        WHERE is_logged_in=true
        AND user_id = $1 ) THEN
        RETURN true;
    ELSE
RETURN false;
END IF;
END
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION office.is_logged_in(integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

`

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug in pgAdmin 4 that generates the incorrect source code.

If you want to run that code, remove `ROWS 0` before running it.

Comment: Yes, that was a bug in pgAdmin4, it has been fixed now & fix will be available in next public release. Ref: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2651